# Using two different ember builds

Tags: ember.js

I am having two different ember builds.
Lets say one is one is parent build and one is child.

Can I have a setup where I can use components from one app inside another app?

Example:
I have added the js,css and vendor js from both the projects in index.html.

```
<script src="../adap/emberapp-parent.js"></script>
<script src="../adap/emberapp-independent.js"></script>
...
```

My main usecase is, I have an parent ember app and I need to use components from another app, which is by itself an independent app.

Is this possible?

Comment: I think in this use case the most common way to handle this is to have a shared set of components / codebase which both builds can make use of (at a high level)

Comment: Did you try ember-engines?